# Porque no imrpime los numeros iguales entre los arreglos arr y multiplos..?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>

var arr=[];
var multiplos=[];
var mayor=0;

for(var n=0; n<4; n++){
    arr.push(parseInt(prompt(n)));
}

for(var c=0; c<=arr.length; c++){

    if(arr[c]>mayor){
        mayor=arr[c];
    }   
}

for(var i=1; i<=mayor; i++){
    multiplos.push(i*3);
}

for(var h=0;  arr[h]<=arr.length; h++){

    for(var j=0; j<=multiplos.length; j++){

        if(multiplos[h] == arr[j]){

            document.write("Esta " + arr[h]);
            document.write("<br>");
        }
    }
}

document.write("Arreglo " + arr);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Multiplos " + multiplos);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Num mayor " + mayor);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>

var arr=[];
var multiplos=[];
var mayor=0;

for(var n=0; n<10; n++){
    arr.push(parseInt(prompt(n)));
}

for(var c=0; c<=arr.length; c++){

    if(arr[c]>mayor){
        mayor=arr[c];
    }   
}


for(var i=0;  i<=arr.length; i++){
        if((arr[i]%3)===0){//valida si es multiplo de 3
            multiplos.push(arr[i]);
        }
}

document.write("Arreglo " + arr);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Multiplos " + multiplos);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Num mayor " + mayor);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder, tu codigo deberia de funcionarme pero no me funciona, al parecer en otra parte en mi codigo tiene algun problema.

Comment: @Jarol quizás no entendí bien la pregunta entonces tengo dos dudas: En donde estas llenando los múltiplos quieres sacar el múltiplo del numero mayor que ingresen? Una vez que tienes eso quieres saber si alguno de ellos esta dentro de tu **arr** ?

Comment: En realidad lo que tengo que hacer es leer 10 numeros y almacenarlos en un arreglo, e imprimir los numeros que son multiplos de 3, que esten dentro del arreglo.

Comment: Lo que hice fue leer los numeros y guardarlos en el arreglo "arr" y guardar una cantidad de multiplos de 3 en el arreglo "multiplo" para entonces comparar los numeros que imgrese en el arreglo "arr", con los multiplos de 3 que tengo guardado en el arreglo "multiplos".

Comment: Prueba nuevamente con el código editado de arriba

Comment: Eres el final bro muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: voto a favor la respuesta si funciono correctamente, saludos

Comment: Si lo hice, es lo menos que podria hacer.

Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente.